# For loop in a Terraform plan?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.14.6
```

I have a Terraform plan that sets up alarms for some of my AWS ECS services, and it looks like this

```
module "ecs_high_cpu_service_aaa_alarm" {
  source       = "../modules/cw_alarm"
  alarm_name   = "ecs-high-cpu-service-aaa-alarm"
  service_name = "service-aaa"
  // Other parameters
}

module "ecs_high_cpu_service_bbb_alarm" {
  source       = "../modules/cw_alarm"
  alarm_name   = "ecs-high-cpu-service-bbb-alarm"
  service_name = "service-bbb"
  // Other parameters
}

module "ecs_high_cpu_service_123_alarm" {
  source       = "../modules/cw_alarm"
  alarm_name   = "ecs-high-cpu-service-123-alarm"
  service_name = "service-123"
  // Other parameters
}

// More alarms with similar setup as above
```

As you can see, the modules are all set up similarly, differing only in name, `alarm_name` and `service_name` parameters. Is there a way to setup a for-loop that will loop over a map to set the modules up for the plan?

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, I credited you on the answer I put below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Mark B's (thanks!) comment, this works.

```
variables.tf
------------
variable "service_map" {
  type        = map
  default     = {
    service-aaa = "ecs-high-cpu-service-aaa-alarm"
    service-bbb = "ecs-high-cpu-service-bbb-alarm"
    service-123 = "ecs-high-cpu-service-123-alarm"
  }
  description = "Service map; key = service name, value = alarm name"
}

main.tf
-------
module "alarms" {
  for_each      = var.service_map
  source        = "../modules/cw_alarm"
  service_name  = each.key
  alarm_name    = each.value
  // Other parameters
}
```